# Install/Uninstall constraint programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint

Is there a way to install and uninstall an Xcode interface builder `constraint` programmatically?

[image]

Comment: take a look at open source project like mansory and pure layout on github. They are better and easier to code

Comment: Is there a way to get this question unclosed, as the meaning of the question is now obvious, and the correct answer is in a comment of an outdated answer?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Connect the IBOutlet for the NSLayoutConstraint  by CTRL+click the constraint and drag it to the viewController (for ex. `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *constraint;`).

For removing the constraint:

```
[self.view removeConstraint:constraint]
```

for installing the constraint:

```
[self.view addConstraint:constraint]
```

Comment: So if a constraint starts out **un**installed, then by `addConstraint` will become installed?

Comment: @Eric "uninstall" is the wrong terminology here...  *uninstall* is strictly in reference to the storyboard and has nothing to do with anything done programmatically at run time.

Comment: @nhgrif So how can I achieve what I wrote in the update?

Comment: This answer should get what you want.

Comment: @nhgrif You're right, but when I add them both in storyboard, I get errors.

Comment: No one can help you with mysterious errors you're not mentioning... but most likely, you need to actually uncheck "installed" for one or the other.

Comment: @Eric what errors are you getting?

Comment: @Eric You could tick the Placeholder remove at build time box of the constraint that you would install programmatically later on

Comment: @nhgrif Then how can I enable them when I need them? (programmatically)?

Comment: @Eric By following this answer.

Comment: @nhgrif So if it's uninstalled, then will `addConstraint` add it?

Comment: @Eric To active or deactivate


`code`NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(constraintsA)
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(constraintsB)`code`

Comment: In iOS 8 there is an `active` property on constraint that corresponds to the "uninstalled" setting in XCode.  Simply leave one constraint uninstalled in XCode with your alternate values and then switch between them by alternating their `active` states at run time.

Comment: Just for the record! It might be dangerous to have a weak reference to the constraint if it will be added/removed in code! It might get released!

Comment: This solution is deprecated. use NSLayoutConstraint's active property instead.